# Display alternative html on a page if a mobile device is used

Tags: html, mobile

Getting very confused here!

I have a simple html page.

I would like to hide certain bits if a mobile device is being used.

How can I do that easily?

It would be the same page that is displayed, just certain bits moved around or hidden if on a mobile.

My issue is that part of the page is shown correctly on mobile devices.

However the bit that I wish to edit is a template within the site.

As a result I am showing the same adverts to mobile and desktop and the same data.

This means my widths are screwed up.

Therefore I really need to hide some bits from mobiles or probably small screens.

I am looking for something I can easily add to my html code.

Answer (score 1):

With [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) you can set rules to hide/show elements depending on screen width.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for detecting mobile devices is to use responsive web design concepts on your existing pages. CSS media queries can be used to define styles for devices of various widths.
Responsive design allows you to create one web page for both mobile and non-mobile users.

Concept of User-Agent can be used if you want to target limited devices.

Example PHP code

```
<?php if (
stristr($ua, "Windows CE") or
stristr($ua, "AvantGo") or
stristr($ua,"Mazingo") or
stristr($ua, "Blazer") ) {
  $DEVICE_TYPE="MOBILE";
}
if (isset($DEVICE_TYPE) and $DEVICE_TYPE=="MOBILE") {
  $location='mobile/index1.php';
  header ('Location: '.$location);
  exit;
}
?>
```